# Pipeline replaces previously deployed lambda when deploying new lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline

I'm referencing [this aws tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/aws-building-a-secure-cross-account-continuous-delivery-pipeline/) to deploy our lambdas cross-account wise.
I'm able to get the lambdas to deploy over successfully but I notice that if I go deploy another lambda `(lambda_b)`, RE-USING the SAME pipeline but for a different lambda, this different lambda `(lambda_b)` will replace the other lambda `(say lambda_a)` that was deployed earlier so that at any time, I only have a single lambda within the aws console.

Could this replacement be happening because of how i'm creating the changeset?
I just don't know how to proceed or where to look to get an idea of why it doesn't deploy `lambda_b` without replacing `lambda_a` even though we're re-using the same pipeline for all lambdas.

To deploy `lambda_a` I had to go through all steps, 1-6 of the tutorial linked above
However, to deploy `lambda_b`, I only rerun step 4 and 5 of the above, is that maybe why? When I try rerunning from the beginning again, it doesn't see the changeset for step 1

[image]

In the codepipiline, cloudformation yaml file, is there a way to set a ***retain:true*** attribute or some kind of way so that I can show all the lambdas that we've deployed so far; right now, i'm only able to show the lambda that was lastly deployed since a new lambda deployment `(lambda_b)` always replaces the old lambda deployment `(lambda_a)`

*`I want the console to show both lambda_a, and lambda_b`*

Comment: are you creating the changeset? then obviously it will replace the old one with new one.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to cloudformation so might ask a lot of newbie questions; but I can't tell developers that they can only see 1 lambda in the aws console; they need to be able to see all deployed lambdas not just the latest one

Comment: Can you please share your cloudformation template, so that we can look and whether any changes in that will solve your problem.

Comment: @VaisakhPS, thanks I'm using this repo: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-refarch-cross-account-pipeline and the pipeline in question is in the `ToolsAccount/` directory; but I can also paste it in here it's just a little long

Comment: If creating the changeset replaces the old one with the new one, then how can I deploy a new lambda without replacing but re-using the SAME pipeline?

Comment: In the the Cloudformation template, replace the `CHANGE_SET_REPLACE` with `CREATE_UPDATE` with new stack name and new lambda function name. This will update the stack, if it exists or create if not. Also it won't replace the stack.  For more see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/continuous-delivery-codepipeline-action-reference.html

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you're using CloudFormation to deploy the lambda function, when a resource (lambda_a) is removed from the template it will be deleted as part of the CloudFormation clean up step.

You need to retain both functions in the template you're deploying to have both lambda_a and lambda_b deployed at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for your response @TimB; I am NOT sure if I understand you correctly but I'm NOT asking about deploying both functions `at the same time i.e simultaneously`; I'm asking about showing all functions that were deployed so far in the lambda console. How would I do what you're suggesting in cloudformation? How do I retain it, is there an attribute on the `pipeline resource` in cloudformation where I can set it to retain? I'm learning cloudformation

Comment: `Configuration:
                ChangeSetName: sample-lambda-dev
                ActionMode: CHANGE_SET_REPLACE` - maybe the issue is around the Change_set_replace attribute? I'm about to google it but maybe it should be set to something like `change_set_retain` to keep the old lambda around? I'm just making that up to show my train of thoughts; that attribute might not even exist

Comment: From this article, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/continuous-delivery-codepipeline-action-reference.html, it looks like maybe I need to use `CHANGE_SET_EXECUTE` instead of `CHANGE_SET_REPLACE`

Comment: Ran into an issue where the changeset didn't previously exist for the new lambda and it failed. CHANGE_SET_REPLACE will create the changeset if it doesn't exist but if it exists, it will DELETE it, so how can I retain the previously deployed lambda? I tried everything I can think of and not sure what else to try

Comment: The codepipeline template in that toolsAccount folder is parameterized on the `projectName`; each `projectName` is a lambda function. We want to reuse the same codepipeline to deploy various lambdas that our developers are writing; so it's a centralized pipeline shared among all devs writing lambda functions. How can I show them all their deployed lambdas instead of just the lastly deployed one; Sorry for writting so much; just wanna give more context in case someone gets an idea of what I'm trying to do or could suggest an article or idea; anything helps; thanks in advanced

Comment: If you want to retain resources that are removed from your CloudFormation template then there's a retain option in the deletion policy. Having said that, I don't recommend doing this for a Lambda function because the function will become "orphaned" by CloudFormation and you won't be able to update it in future from CloudFormation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-deletionpolicy.html